# How can I create a Seq[Array[Double]] for a matrix multiplication?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, scala, matrix

```
class MatrixMultiplication {
  def singleThreadedMultiplication(m1:Seq[Array[Double]], m2:Array[Array[Double]] ) ={
    val res =  Array.fill(m1.length, m2(0).length)(0.0)

    for(row <- 0 until m1.length;
        col <- 0 until m2(0).length;
        i   <- 0 until m1(0).length){
      res(row)(col) += m1(row)(i) * m2(i)(col)
    }

    res
  }
}
```

__

```
object multiplication {
  def main(args : Seq[Array[Double]], args2 : Array[Double]) : Unit = {
    val matrixmult = new MatrixMultiplication
    var b = new Array[Double](4)
    b = Array(2,1,2,1)
    seq: Seq[Double] = WrappedArray(1, 0, 2, 0)
    matrixmult.singleThreadedMultiplication(Seq[Double],b)
  }
}
```

All I need is to know how I can run the single threaded multiplication method since its 1st parameter is `Seq[Array[Double]]` and I have no idea and I didn't manage to find any way how to create a seq double array in the second class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Seq` is a trait and there are many subclasses that implement it. `List` and `ArrayBuffer` for example. So, you can create an `Array[Array[Double]]` and pass that to `singleThreadedMultiplication`. The appropriate type can be created with `val array = Array(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0))` and passed to `m1` or `m2` in `singleThreadedMultiplication` for example.

```
object multiplication {
  def main(args : Seq[Array[Double]], args2 : Array[Double]) : Unit = {
    val matrixmult = new MatrixMultiplication
    matrixmult.singleThreadedMultiplication(args, Array(args2)
  }
}
```

To run it and use the parameters passed in remove these lines since they are not used.

```
var b = new Array[Double](4)
b = Array(2,1,2,1)
seq: Seq[Double] = WrappedArray(1, 0, 2, 0)
```

Then change the call to use the parameters passed in.

```
matrixmult.singleThreadedMultiplication(args, Array(args2))
```

This runs but you have an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the `singleThreadedMultiplication` function.

```
scala> val a = Array(2.0,1.0,2.0,1.0)
b: Array[Double] = Array(2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0)

scala> val b = Array(Array(1.0,0.0,2.0,0.0))
c: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0))

scala> multiplication.main(b, a)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at MatrixMultiplication$$anonfun$singleThreadedMultiplication$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$2.apply$mcVI$sp
...
```

Comment: It will build like this. But, to run it you will have to create `c` and `d` first and then pass them into `main or change the `main` function.

Comment: but c and d do not already have a value? (1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0) etc?

Comment: The value of `c` is `Array(Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0))`. Is it intentional that `args2` is defined like this `args2 : Array[Double]` and not like the other parameters `Seq[Array[Double]]`?

Comment: I am new to Scala, this was an assignment in which we had to find code that implement certain functions and we have to run them, and understand the coding while explaining the lines of code.

In the main class:
class MatrixMultiplication {
  def singleThreadedMultiplication(m1:Seq[Array[Double]], m2:Array[Array[Double]] ) ={

The second parameter doesnt have the Seq before it, so I guess the person who did it, did it on purpose.

Finally can you explain better how can i run the program? thank you very very much

Comment: `Array` is not a subclass of `Seq`.

Comment: so what should I do to run? find another method?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Thanks. Looks like the implicit conversion `scala.Predef.wrapDoubleArray` converts it to a `WrappedArray` which satisfies the `Seq` constraint in this case.

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri I've edited the answer to show an example how to run it using the parameters passed in which is one way to do it and I am guessing what you intended. You can also not use the parameters passed in like in your example.

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri You should tag this post and others as homework. Also, if this has been helpful feel free to vote accordingly.

Comment: i cant vote up mate because I need reputation. but thanks very much for ure help